# Init.d script for Rails managing a Rails app via Unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, linux

This script is to enable the remote management of a Rails app via one script.
I pieced it together from various blog posts. I am not to familiar with some of the BASH functionality that is used. It seems to work okay, but I wonder if there is anything that I have done sub-optimally in my naïveté.

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/unicorn

# ### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Stop/start unicorn
### END INIT INFO

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

PROJ_ENV="staging"
RBENV_VERSION=2.2.2
RBENV_ROOT=/opt/rbenv

PROJ_NAME="myapp"

PID_FILE=/var/www/$PROJ_NAME/current/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
OLD_PID_FILE=$PID_FILE.oldbin
PROJ_DIR=/var/www/$PROJ_NAME
TAG='[unicorn]'

UNICORN_CONFIG=$PROJ_DIR/current/config/unicorn/$PROJ_ENV.rb
DEPLOY_USER=ec2-user
[ -f $PID_FILE ] && KPID=`cat $PID_FILE`

# Start the service
start() {
     # [ is the 'test' command  -f file? -a and -n variable -d directory
    if [ -f $PID_FILE -a -n "${KPID}" -a -d "/proc/${KPID}" ]; then
          logger -sit $TAG "Process ${KPID} in PID file $PID_FILE exists. Service '${PROJ_NAME}' should be running"
        exit 1
    else
        logger -sit "$TAG" "Process doesn't exist. Trying to start server..."
        #su - $DEPLOY_USER -c "bash -c 'cd $PROJ_DIR/current ; pwd      ; /opt/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec unicorn -v'"
        su - $DEPLOY_USER -c "bash -c 'cd $PROJ_DIR/current ; pwd       ; /opt/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec unicorn -c $UNICORN_CONFIG -E $PROJ_ENV -D'"
        if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
            logger -sit "$TAG" "server started"
        else
            logger -sit "$TAG" "FAILED to start server"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
}

# Stop the service
stop() {
        su $DEPLOY_USER -c "kill -TERM $(cat $PID_FILE)"
        sleep 2
        if [[ ! -f $PID_FILE ]]; then
                logger -sit "$TAG" "Server stoped"
        else
                logger -sit "$TAG" "FAILED to stop server"
                exit 1
        fi
}

# Reload service
reload() {
    logger -sit "$TAG" "Trying to reload server"
    kill -USR2 $(cat $PID_FILE)
    sleep 1
    if [[ -f $OLD_PID_FILE ]]; then
        logger -sit "$TAG" "Server reloaded"
    else
        logger -sit "$TAG" "FAILED to reload server"
        exit 1
    fi
}

restart() {
    if [ -f $PID_FILE -a -n "${KPID}" -a -d "/proc/${KPID}" ]; then
        logger -sit "$TAG" "Restarting server"
        kill -HUP $(cat $PID_FILE)
    else
      logger -sit "$TAG" "Process doesn't exist. Running start"
       #$0 is the path of the script
      $0 start
    fi
}

### main logic ###
case "$1" in
    start)
        start
        ;;

    stop)
        stop
        ;;

    restart)
        restart
        ;;
    reload)
        reload
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload}"
        exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quoting command line arguments

This is not safe:

> ```
> [ -f $PID_FILE ] && ...
> ```

Variables and the result of $(...) should be double-quoted to protect from parameter expansion and globbing:

```
[ -f "$PID_FILE" ] && ...
```

A longer example (fixed version, compare with your original):

```
if [ -f "$PID_FILE" -a -n "${KPID}" -a -d "/proc/${KPID}" ]; then
      logger -sit "$TAG" "Process ${KPID} in PID file $PID_FILE exists. Service '${PROJ_NAME}' should be running"
```

The lack of quoting is the most common violation in the posted code,
review carefully.
Copy-paste to https://www.shellcheck.net/, it should help.

#### Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``

The backtick format is obsolete, and harder to read. Always use `$(...)`.

#### Usability

The `stop` function waits for 2 seconds after sending the `TERM` signal to the process to check if the PID file still exists.
That seems a bit arbitrary, and possibly fragile.
It would be better to sleep for 1 second 5 times in a loop.
This is also pretty arbitrary, but a bit more flexible.

#### Pointless `` [ -f $PID_FILE ] && KPID=`cat $PID_FILE` ``

This is executed always, regardless of the sub-command.
And then most sub-commands reload the value in `$PID_FILE`.
It would be better to create a function for getting the PID,
and calling that function when you need it.

#### Signal to PID that might not exist

Some of the functions signal to `$(cat "$PID_FILE")`,
without making sure that PID actually exists,
or even that `$PID_FILE` actually exists.
It would be better to validate the state more accurately,
and raise errors as appropriate.

#### Recursive execution

The `restart` function calls `$0 start` to restart the script.
It would be more natural to simply call the `start` function directly.